# Power BI conditional difference between start date and today

Tags: powerbi

Power BI newbie here. I have a table of defect data, each row is a different defect. For each row, if the column 'state' is NOT equal to 'validated', I want the column 'Age' to be the difference between the submit date and today. But if the column 'state' IS equal to 'validated', I want the column 'Age' to be the difference between the submit date and validation date.

I successfully created the 'Age' column, but it shows (today - create date) for all of them, even the validated rows. This isn't quite what I need because that gives misleading numbers for validated defects.

I might have gotten it:

```
Test = IF('QueryResultModified'[State] = "Validated", DATEDIFF('QueryResultModified'[Validation Date], 'QueryResultModified'[Submit Date],DAY), DATEDIFF(TODAY(), 'QueryResultModified'[Submit Date],DAY)) * -1
```

Comment: This can be done with a simple dax expression, add you code so we can help you